# Python h2o cluster freezes at parse progress

Tags: python, h2o

Problem Specific to Mac OS Mojave.

I am using the python library of h2o and while predicting the h2o cluster freezes. I am able to access the logs through flow but there are no failures in it.

I have tried `h2o.init(model,min_mem_size = "16g")` also.

I think it be an issue with h2o unable to access my mac lib folder?

I am basing the guess on:

```
$user qalex$ java -jar app/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/bin/h2o.jar

Cannot load library from path lib/osx_64/libxgboost4j_gpu.dylib
Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_gpu.dylib
Failed to load library from both native path and jar!
Cannot load library from path lib/osx_64/libxgboost4j_omp.dylib
Cannot load library from path lib/libxgboost4j_omp.dylib
```

[image: Parse progress freezes]

My H2O version:

```
pip install -f http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_Py.html 'h2o==3.22.1.1'
```

These log Files are empty:

```
h2o_127.0.0.1_54321-6-warn.log
h2o_127.0.0.1_54321-6-fatal.log
h2o_127.0.0.1_54321-6-error.log
```

Let me know if you need me to upload these files somewhere?

```
h2o_127.0.0.1_54321-6-info.log
h2o_127.0.0.1_54321-6-httpd.log
h2o_qalex_started_from_python.err (nevermind works only with linux)
h2o_qalex_started_from_python.out (nevermind works only with linux)
```

Comment: how big is the file you are trying to upload? thanks!

Comment: It is around 100MB. Also this is a problem specific to Mac OS Mojave.

Comment: It needs 26GB of H2O Free Cluster Memory on CDSW